# Subset data frame using row names

Tags: r, subset, r-rownames

I have a data frame like this:

```
       x1    x2    x3
271    3     5      2
553    2     4      1
563    2     5      3
```

When I try to select a row based on the row name, e.g. 271, it errors:

```
df[271, ]
# Error in xj[i, , drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds
```

How can I select these rows based on the row names (e.g. 271, 553, 563)?

Comment: Row name in apostrophes: `DFsubset['271',]`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to reference the rownames of your data.frame:

```
dfsub[rownames(dfsub) == 271,] #where dfsub is your subsetted data.frame
```

EDIT:

as @koekenbakker commented, there is a shorthand to reference the rownames by using `''`. So this would be:

```
dfsub['271',] #where dfsub is your subsetted data.frame and 271 the rowname
```