# How to extract values of a dataframe based on a vector containing the row names of the dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df`, which is as follows. The left-hand side is the row names and the first column is the corresponding values.

```
              v1   
 a177:a1297  0.1
 a177:a842   0.2
 a177:a796   0.4
 a24:a1437   0.3
 a24:a1256   0.6
 a24:a762    0.7
```

I have a vector of characters which are the row names of `df`. The vector is `dfnames`

```
  str(dfnames)
  chr [1:5] "a177:a1297" "a177:a842" "a177:a796" "a24:a1437" "a24:a1256" "a24:a762"
```

If I extract one value based on a specific row name, it would be:

```
    df["a177:a1297",]
   [1]  0.1
```

Now I want to extract all the values of `df` based on `dfnames`

```
  df[dfnames,]
  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Could anyone tell me how to extract the values of `df` based on a `vector` that contains the `row names` of `df`?

Comment: That's weird, it works for me. I get `> df[dfnames, ] \n
[1] 0.1 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.6 0.7`

Comment: Passing a string should work, please make your problem reproducible. Try this example: `df1 <- mtcars[1:10, 1:3]; myRows <- c("Valiant", "Duster 360"); df1[myRows, ]`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23652566/how-can-i-select-a-row-by-row-name-in-a-subsetted-data-frame-in-r

Comment: That is what I want. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
df[which(row.names(df) %in% dfnames),]
```